# 'Overloaded' MVC Routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using ASP.NET MVC routes to direct traffic based on certain words, for instance `mydomain.com/support` which directs to the support page (under the Home controller), or `mydomain.com/controller/action/id` as per default.

However I would also like traffic to have the ability to use any single word after the gTLD - that I haven't already specified - to hit my home page.

For instance: `mydomain.com/anything` would still hit my home page and not produce a 404 response. Where *anything* is any word other than what I have already specified (so in this example "support").

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just do something like this don't you?

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "MyRoute",
  "{word}.aspx",
    new { 
      controller = "Home",
      action = "Index"
  }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

?

And update your action (**Index** in this case to have a **word** parameter).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to do this because by this you can end up indexing lot of requests by search engines.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "MyRoute",
  "{anything}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

This route should be at last after the default route.

If you want even this kind of requests http://mydomain.com/anything/otherthing/another to still handle by Home controller then you have to try,

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "CatchAllRoute",
  "{*anything}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: Would this cause SEO bad times re: search results?

Comment: Are you going to give same response for all those requests? if that is the case then it may reduce the page rank. If you give the same response to the browser for two different urls that will reduce the page rank.